# Why don't I get a recursive infinite loop when throwing an error in the onError function?

Tags: coldfusion, error-handling, infinite-loop, application.cfc, onerror

In my coldfusion Application.cfc file, I define an onError function. In certain situations, I explicitly throw an exception using a cfthrow tag - e.g. `<cfthrow object="#myException#">`. My question is, why doesn't this create an infinite loop? Or at least cause another call to the onError function? (Instead, it just dumps the error to the screen. Which is the functionality I want, actually :) - but I'm still confused about why this happens.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected and documented behavior:

[If an exception occurs while processing the onError method, or if the onError method uses a cfthrow tag, the ColdFusion standard error handling mechanisms handle the exception.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=AppEvents_06.html)

Comment: To expand on that a bit, it means that if you have any CFError tags in your Application.cfc (only when using a tag-based Application.cfc), they will be used, followed by the server settings.