# How to re-trigger the default error screen from the onError function in application.cfc using ColdFusion 11?

Tags: error-handling, coldfusion

I use the onError function inside Application.cfc to integrate with RayGun when the code is on live but when we are on dev I'd like to be able to revert back to the normal ColdFusion error event. At the moment I have some basic error handling in place but it isn't as good as the default ColdFusion behavior. Does anybody know if this is possible and how?

I intend to add this as a feature request for ColdFusion 12 if there is no way of doing it.

Comment: could you rethrow inside Application.cfc when you're on a dev environment. Failing that how about just dumping out the onError arguments?

Comment: If I rethrow then I'll trigger an infinite loop. I do currently dump the onerror arguments but that falls far short of the presentation and effort put into the default error page. I appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Is that statement about the infinite loop based on observation or speculation?

Comment: Out of curiousity, I tried the rethrow.  It caused this error.  `Context validation error for the cfrethrow tag.  
It must be nested inside a cfcatch tag.  `

Comment: hmm. I didn't try it. I should have. My bad.

Comment: [Why don't I get a recursive infinite loop when throwing an error in the onError function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544623/why-dont-i-get-a-recursive-infinite-loop-when-throwing-an-error-in-the-onerror)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works when I run it.

in Application.cfc

```
<cffunction name="onError" access="public" returntype="void">
<cfargument name="Exception" required=true type="any">
<cfif true>
<cfthrow object="#arguments.exception#">
<cfelse>
error
</cfif>
</cffunction>
```

in cfm page.

```
<cfscript>
X=Y;  // Y is undefined
</cfscript>
```

All you have to do is replace `<cfif true>` with something that identifies your development environment.

Comment: Oh. This is such an obvious solution. I feel ashamed not to have tried this. Thanks for your answer.